# how to use reduce to update a map

Tags: clojure

I have a string **"101,R:102,R:301,L:302,L:999"**, and I want to write a function, which processes the string and return a map like below:

```
{
  :left     [301 302],
  :right    [101 102],
  :unknown  [999]
}
```

Below is what I wrote, but I am stuck at the reduce function. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
(defn process
  [data return-hash]
  (let [id-side (str/split data #",")
        id (first id-side)
        side (second id-side)]
    (cond
      (= "L" side) (update-in return-hash [:left] conj id)
      (= "R" side) (update-in return-hash [:right] conj id)
      :else (update-in return-hash [:unknown] conj id)
      )
    ))

(defn get-hash
  [data]
  (let [id-side-array (str/split data #":")]
    (reduce
      // a function calling process() method to update the map
      id-side-array)
    ))

(get-hash "101,R:102,R:301,L:302,L:999") 
=> 
{
  :left     [301 302],
  :right    [101 102],
  :unknown  [999]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're actually almost there:

1. Change parameter order of `process` so that `return-hash` comes first;
2. Use `(fnil conj [])` in place of `conj` in the `update-in` calls;
3. Use `(reduce process {} id-side-array)` in `get-hash`.

Comment: Wow, this is wonderful!!   Thank you very much Michael for your help!  I would give it 10 points if I could.

Comment: I am new to Clojure, I know this code can be shorter and more precise.  Thanks for the help again.